# React Native - What's the library for signing in using Apple ID

Tags: ios, react-native

I found the library used to help me sign in with google play services but i found nothing to help me sign in using the apple store

I need help finding the docs on how to do it

Comment: Were you able to integrate Apple-SignIn. if yes then how? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HashirSaeed this worked for me: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Currently this seems to be the most used option:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-apple-authentication